# Date problem when importing from file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, load-data-infile

I have a table with `payDate DATETIME` in which I'm inserting using `load data local infile 'file.txt' into table tableName;` dates like *26/04/2012 00:00:00*.

This gives warnings like `Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'payDate' at row 1` and the date in the table is *0000-00-00 00:00:00*.

Is there any way to specify the format of the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
load data local infile 'file.txt' into table tableName 
SET payDate = str_to_date(@payDate, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Comment: Sounds right but why am I getting "Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'payDate' at row 1" and a NULL is inserted?

Comment: I needed to add '%h:%i:%s' or '00:00:00'

Answer (score 1):

I worked out without converting from datetime to varchar ,
Below is the working code for it -

### mysql query to export csv data to local directory

```
SELECT organization_id,bank_name,branch_name,account_number,statement_type,parameter_name,
parameter_value,created_by,creation_date,updated_by,updation_date FROM cm_sub_param_values
    INTO OUTFILE 'D:\mytable.csv'
    FIELDS ESCAPED BY '""'
    TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

In the csv exported , remove the column names and SAVE.

In the Table , creation_date and updation_date are of type  datetime .

### Import CSV data into mysql

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/mytable.csv' IGNORE 
    INTO TABLE `cm_sub_param_values` 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\''
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
    (sub_param_id,organization_id,bank_name,branch_name,account_number,
statement_type,parameter_name,parameter_value,created_by,@creation_date,updated_by,@updation_date)
    SET creation_date = STR_TO_DATE(@creation_date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'),
    updation_date = STR_TO_DATE(@updation_date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') ;
```

Import Successful !

Answer (score 0):

You would want to modify those variables before loading :
[Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_date_format)

- set column type to VARCHAR
- LOAD DATA INFILE
- UPDATE SET column = DATE_FORMAT( str_to_date(column, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d' )
- set column type back to DATE
- SHOW WARNINGS